# Scaling: What’s the difference between Ctrl+A and S?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shortcut

I saw some blender tutorials, and a doubt arises to me. Whats the difference between using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and  <kbd>S</kbd> to scale something?

For instance, I modeled some branches using *Skin* modifier and if I select a vertex and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> it allows me to scale but not using the  <kbd>S</kbd> key.

Comment: Note that Ctrl+A in Edit mode is applicable only if Skin modifier is present as it changes attribute of the vertices used by modifier

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> while in *Edit Mode* changes the vertex radius; nothing else.

Only things like modifiers that use that property of the vertex to change something are affected. It's a nondestructive and indirect way of control since it only affects functions that read that value from the vertex.

Scaling on the other hand, at least in *Edit Mode* actually changes the mesh. It moves stuff to or away from the current pivot point. It is direct manipulation of the mesh.